# Convert a DStream to a Data Frame

Tags: scala, apache-spark, bigdata

Hi I am trying to read tweets from Twitter using Apache Spark Streaming and trying to convert to a DataFrame. I have the approach that I have pasted below. However, I am not beign able to get the correct approach. Some pointers would be welcome.

As you can see converting to DF inside the foreach does not get me a single DF from tweetStream. I probably have the wrong approach as I am new to this. How do I approach this?

```
val tweetStream = TwitterUtils.createStream(ssc, Utils.getAuth).filter(status=>status.getLang=="en")
      .map(status=>gson.toJson(status))
    val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
    import sqlContext.implicits._
    tweetStream.foreachRDD({status=>val DF = status.toDF()})
```

Comment: I was thinking of using a DF.merge() inside a loop to get the entire DF computed inside foreachRDD{}

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried it, but maybe something like this works:

```
  var df_tweets:DataFrame = null

  dstream_tweets.foreachRDD {
    rrd => if (df_tweets != null) {
      df_tweets = df_tweets.unionAll(rdd.toDF) // combine previous dataframe
    } else {
      df_tweets = rdd.toDF() // create new dataframe
      }
    }
```